# can we have a bpmn file in camunda 7 that has more than one http-connector?

Tags: camunda, camunda-modeler

can we have a bpmn file in **camunda 7** that has **more than one** http-connector or just only one service task with type = http-connector can put in a process?
[image]

Comment: Check out Camunda 8. The connector concept and offering is way more sophisticated there. Also see https://marketplace.camunda.com

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple activities of the same type and this includes also the http connector, which is just a special kind of service task.
Important is, that the id of the activity is unique inside your process definition.